# Why program header segment virtual address is 0x40004000?

Tags: linux, memory, header, virtual, elf

I am studying some things about the ELF format (on a x64 Linux platform) and in the program header the first segment (PT_PHDR) has this virtual address `0x40004000` (alignment is  8 bytes). I don't understand and I don't find a place where that is explained. In some other examples on the Internet it is `0x08048034` and I don't know if this is because of the OS or the processor architecture. Is there a place where these fixed values are listed and briefly explained, like a reference book or manual or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on a x64 Linux platform

That platform *does not exist*. You mean `Linux x86_64` platform.

> (PT_PHDR) has this virtual address 0x40004000

That is a very strange address. Are you sure it's not `0x400040` ?

> I don't understand and I don't find a place where that is explained. In some other examples on the Internet it is 0x08048034 and I don't know if this is because of the OS or the processor architecture.

For `Linux x86_64`, the default address where the executable is linked is `0x400000`, and the size of `Elf64_Ehdr` (which is at the start of every ELF binary) is `64`, giving you *default* `PT_PHDR` address of `0x400040`.

For `Linux i*86`, the default address for executables is `0x08048000`, and the size of `Elf32_Ehdr` is `52`, giving you the *default* `PT_PHDR` address of `0x08048034`.

Either of these addresses can be changed by e.g. using the linker `-Ttext=0xNNNN` flag.